# Android multiple content-providers, (DLC)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I am looking to add additional content to my app as extra databases.
Should I put them in apks and content providers, so they can be updated from google play directly, or just as new db files downloaded straight into the app.

My problem with the content-provider/apk method, is they all have to be declared in the android manifest, and I might have multiple databases even hundreds, so would need 100s of content-provider declarations in my manifest, even when the user may have only a couple or even none of them.

Unless there is a way I can generate the manifest dynamically? Or load the content-providers outside of the manifest?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, have I been an idiot all this time? Are the content providers you declare in your manifest ones for your app to read from, or ones within your app that other apps can read from?

Comment: ContentProvider is for both externals app and current app. You can specify the correct behavior using the `exported` boolean as described here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported

Comment: So, I declare the provider in the manifest of the app where the data is stored, correct? I was making the mistake of looking at it from the other perspective, in that I had to declare in my app which content-providers I wanted to read from!

Comment: Yes, you declare the provider in the app that contains the data. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the cleanest way to do this is to have **one unique** [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) for all your db files.

You should build your [URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html)'s around database selection.

For example : `content://com.your.package/a_db_file/something/things/5`

Then when implementing your ContentProvider, parse the Uri to get the `a_db_file` segment, open the corresponding db file, then do the needed work according to the rest of the segments.

Maybe you will need a method like `getCorrectDb(String a_db_file)`.
Inside this method you should make the correct call to a [sqlLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) that properly match the needed db file.

Also take a look at [UriMatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html), it might be useful for you. :)

In the end you should have something like:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    // TODO : Parse uri to get a_db_file string.

    SQLiteDatabase database = getCorrectDb(a_db_file);

    // TODO : get cursor from db according to other segments of uri.

    return cursor.

}
```

Comment: Ok, if I have one provider with multiple db in, how can I update the content in those dbs? If I have separate providers in apks, then can't I use Google play to update the individual apk and hence db?

Comment: `Ok, if I have one provider with multiple db in, how can I update the content in those dbs?` Same as the example with `query` but with the `update` method of the provider. The Uri you give (`getContentResolver().update(uri ...`) should have a segment that match a Db. Think about a ContentProvider as a big tool to manage access to one or more database. It is up to you how you organize the work. :)

Comment: If you want to have one apk for one db, it is possible. Then it will be possible to update just one apk to update the db. But you will have as many apk as db files and then it will be **a lot** harder to maintain ... Why don't you update your db using a http request / json etc. ?

Comment: I think your app should connect to a server of yours on start up. Check if the db needs to be updated. Update the db using your content provider if needed.

Comment: Just to understand a bit better your problem, what contains all those db ?

Comment: Thinking about it, I think I will need multiple apks, as I will also be containing images and audio (mp3) as well as db, and all of these will be different for each apk. 

I do like the idea of it checking if there needs to be any updates on startup. However, I will also need to allow the user to install/uninstall the db/apk whenever they want, and I think that using apks should make this easier, am I right?

Comment: I don't really know ... You probably have a better understanding of the context of your app. Just do what feel right. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use one content provider to keep things simple and utilize the "attach database" sql command.